# Error when trying to print a number of messages spread across one second

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following infinite loop I try to print 40 messages per second. At the same time I try to spread the prints as evenly as possible across each second. The problem is that after printing approximately 38  messages the sleep time becomes a negative number and I get a "ValueError: sleep length must be non-negative" error. I have noticed that the sleep time starts at 0.025 and goes gradually down to a negative number after 38 or 39 prints. Any idea how to better calculate a sleep time so that the prints are evenly spread but I don't run into this error ?

```
duration = 1.0
target = 40

start = time.time()
while True:
    print("Hello")
    target -= 1
    if target:
        time.sleep((duration + start - time.time()) / target)
    else:
        start = time.time()
        target = 40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be time.time() - start.

```
import time
import sys
duration = 1.0
target = 40

start = time.time()
count = 0
while True:
    print("Hello")
    count = count + 1
    target -= 1
    if count == 40:
        sys.exit(0)
    if target:
        time.sleep((duration + time.time() - start) / target)
    else:
        start = time.time()
        target = 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be something like this:

```
import time

while 1:
   print("Some Message\n"*40)
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This prints all messages at once not evenly spread across one second

Comment: You want one message to print in one second or all 40 messages in one second?